# Python create sequence of numbers and append by group

Tags: python, pandas

I want to append a sequence of numbers by group ID.

I have a column that looks like this:

```
ID [123, 124...]
```

I need to append a sequence of numbers (1:485) to each unique ID so that the final data frame looks like this:

```
ID     [123, 123, 123, 123, 124, 124, 124, 124...]
Number [1,    2,   3,   4,   1,   2 ,  3,   4...]
```

Does anyone have simple guidance?

Comment: Is ``ID`` part of pandas ``dataframe`` of just a plain ``list`` ?

Comment: Part of the data frame

Comment: The problem is that I'm not counting the groups, I'm assigning the sequence to them. The sequence is from 1 to 485, and I want to copy each row (read: ID) and assign it a number in that sequence. Therefore, there should be 485 copies of each ID row. Cumcount doesn't address it

Answer (score 2):

You can repeat the index 485 times and `loc` with it to expand. `cumcount` then gives the 1...485 counts per ID:

```
new_df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(485)].reset_index(drop=True)
new_df["Number"] = new_df.groupby("ID").cumcount().add(1)
```

to get

```
>>> new_df

      ID  Number
0    123       1
1    123       2
2    123       3
3    123       4
4    123       5
..   ...     ...
965  124     481
966  124     482
967  124     483
968  124     484
969  124     485

[970 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I always like the repeat solution +1. I tend to err towards reindex incase there are multiple of the same ID. But this is definitely more performant when it can be used. :)

Answer (score 1):

We can create a [`MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) IDs and the new range of values (created with [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)).

Then enumerate the IDs already present in the DataFrame with [`Groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

Then [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123, 124], 'x1': ['a', 'b']})

u_id = df['ID'].unique()
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([u_id, np.arange(1, 486)],
                                  names=['ID', 'Number'])
df = (
    df.assign(Number=df.groupby('ID').cumcount() + 1)
        .set_index(['ID', 'Number'])
        .reindex(midx, method='ffill')
        .reset_index()
)
print(df)
```

`df`:

```
      ID  Number x1
0    123       1  a
1    123       2  a
2    123       3  a
3    123       4  a
4    123       5  a
..   ...     ... ..
965  124     481  b
966  124     482  b
967  124     483  b
968  124     484  b
969  124     485  b

[970 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This worked but erased my other variables (x1,x2,x3,x4). What is the solution for retaining those as well? Thanks a lot for pushing this in the right direction

Comment: Yes. We can use a combination of `groupby cumcount` and `reindex`. Try the edit.